# null values in NHibernate returning list

Tags: c#, nhibernate, null

I'm trying to understand the following behaviour of NHibernate and can't.

```
session.CreateCriteria<Param>()
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("GroupId", groupId))
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ParamId", paramId))
  .List<Param>()
```

This construction should return collection with 1 database row(object). But returns list with single null element. Could you suggest why?

P.S. Param class mapping has a composite key.

```
public class Param
{
    public Param()
    {
    }
    public Param(string groupId, string paramId, string paramName) : this()
    {
        GroupId = groupId;
        ParamId = paramId;
        ParamName = paramName;
    }
    public virtual string GroupId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string ParamId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string ParamName { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj){...}
    public override int GetHashCode(){...}
}

public class ParamMap : ClassMap<Param>
{
    public ParamMap()
    {
        Table("Params");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.GroupId)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ParamId)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ParamName, "ParamName");

        Map(x => x.Value, "ParamValue");
    }
}
```

This query is copied from database log. NHibernate executes it.

```
SELECT THIS_.GROUPID AS GROUPID19_0_, THIS_.PARAMID AS PARAMID19_0_,
THIS_.PARAMNAME AS PARAMNAME19_0_, THIS_.PARAMVALUE AS PARAMVALUE19_0_
FROM PARAMS THIS_ WHERE THIS_.GROUPID = :1 AND THIS_.PARAMID = :2 
\
WorkHour,TotalHours, 
/
```

Returns 1 row:

```
GroupId = "WorkHour"
ParamId = "TotalHours"
ParamName = (empty) 
ParamValue = YES
```

Comment: Could you tell us more about the Param class and the values in the DB?

Comment: tried without the _protected_ modifier on the key properties ? Also, do your Equals and GetHashCode handle the null value of paramName correctly ?

Comment: Another classes works perfectly with protected modifier in primary key fields, but I will try, thank you. GetHashCode won't be called in null object. Equals have a needed check.

Answer (score 0):

That was my fault. The ParamName value is not empty string. It's null! So, this is strange behaviour of NHibernate but reason is found.